# Error when running any kivy code: Kivy 2.0.0 , python 3.9 error: [CRITICAL] [Window ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, kivy

I've been having this same error running any kivy code I type into IntelliJ. I'm using kivy 2.0.0 and Python 3.9.
Here's my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
Screen:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "It works!"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.7}
            text_size: self.size
        """


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return self.screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I've tried many solutions including reinstalling kivy, adding to path, and I've installed all the dependencies.
Here's the error message:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\James\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-10-25_21.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\james\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge 9 log files
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
2.0.0
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### **EDIT**
So thanks to Weebify I got through. Just Follow all the download instructions from the kivy docs exactly. I posted the full method I used as an answer (not marked as best answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to uninstall `kivy` and reinstall the cutting-edge version from master:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall kivy
python3 -m pip install "kivy[base] @ https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I did the above in command prompt and no difference, I also tried it in the IntelliJ terminal but no difference.

Comment: Weird, it works for many people, including me

Comment: I just remember what I had to do to make it work. Try reinstalling Python and run the commands I provided above in a cmd/powershell/terminal with administrator permission

Comment: thank you so much I got it to work

Comment: Below is the code I used:

Comment: This is for windows OS in cmd

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so many thanks to Weebify for help here. Here are the full download instructions for Windows for anyone who is having problems:

‎

### **NOTE: Kivy does not yet support Python 3.10 but you can get through fine with Python 3.9**

‎

### **Setup terminal and pip**

Before Kivy can be installed, **Python and pip need to be pre-installed**. Then, start a new terminal that has Python available. In the terminal, update pip and other installation dependencies so you have the latest version as follows, *(for linux users you may have to substitute python3 instead of python and also add a --user flag in the subsequent commands outside the virtual environment):*

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools virtualenv
```

---

### **Create virtual environment**

1. Create a new virtual environment for your Kivy project. A virtual
   environment will prevent possible installation conflicts with other
   Python versions and packages. It’s optional but strongly
   recommended:

Create the virtual environment named kivy_venv in your current directory:

```
python -m virtualenv kivy_venv
```

2. Activate the virtual environment. You will have to do this step from
   the current directory every time you start a new terminal. This sets
   up the environment so the new kivy_venv Python is used.

For Windows default CMD, in the command line do:

```
kivy_venv\Scripts\activate
```

If you are in a bash terminal on Windows, instead do:

```
source kivy_venv/Scripts/activate
```

If you are in Linux, instead do:

```
source kivy_venv/bin/activate
```

Your terminal should now preface the path with something like (kivy_venv), indicating that the kivy_venv environment is active. If it doesn’t say that, the virtual environment is not active and the following won’t work.

---

### **Install Kivy**

Finally, **install Kivy using the latest cutting-edge Kivy from master:**

```
python -m pip install "kivy[base] @ https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip"
```

More info on the [Kivy installation page.](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html)