# ImportError: DLL load failed kivy

Tags: kivy

Although if run in debug mode, it works. How to fix?

trying use conda, but it's not working too.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\AlexK\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-06-18_0.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\AlexK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\AlexK\PycharmProjects\learning_project\MyArchive\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06 (installed at "C:\Users\AlexK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: Не найден указанный модуль.
  File "C:\Users\AlexK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
File "C:\Users\AlexK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712748/error-when-running-any-kivy-code-kivy-2-0-0-python-3-9-error-critical-win